# Ruby: Invert a hash to also preserve non unique values

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash that looks like this:

```
{"a" => [1, 2, 3], "b" => [4, 5, 6], "c" => [3, 4, 5], "d" => [7, 2, 3]}
```

What I want to do is to make a hash of all existing values with an array of all keys that included it, e.g. turn the above into this:

```
{1 => ["a"], 2 => ["a", "d"], 3 => ["a", "c", "d"], 4 => ["b", "c"]}
```

Comment: @mikej Please again compare this question with the one you referenced.  I do not understand the claim that this question is a duplicate of the former one. The previous question required a straightforward use of `invert`. That cannot be used here.

Comment: @Cary, sorry, you're right. Have re-opened. I think the title of this question could be improved, but the example does make it clear.

Comment: "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
is a good read. We need more than requirements, we need to see an attempt to solve the problem. Questions containing requirements only feel like you're asking us to write the code for you, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do prefer @Jikku's solution, but there's always another way. Here's one. 
(I see this is very close to @Chris's solution. I will leave it for the last line, which is a little different.)

**Code**

```
def inside_out(h)
  g = h.flat_map { |s,a| a.product([s]) }
       .group_by(&:first)
  g.merge(g) { |_,a| a.map(&:last) }
end
```

**Example**

```
h = {"a" => [1, 2, 3], "b" => [4, 5, 6], "c" => [3, 4, 5], "d" => [7, 2, 3]}

inside_out(h)
  #=> {1=>["a"], 2=>["a", "d"], 3=>["a", "c", "d"], 4=>["b", "c"],
  #    5=>["b", "c"], 6=>["b"], 7=>["d"]}
```

**Explanation**

For `h` above:

```
a = h.flat_map { |s,a| a.product([s]) }
  #=> [[1, "a"], [2, "a"], [3, "a"], [4, "b"], [5, "b"], [6, "b"],
  #    [3, "c"], [4, "c"], [5, "c"], [7, "d"], [2, "d"], [3, "d"]] 
g = a.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {1=>[[1, "a"]], 2=>[[2, "a"], [2, "d"]],
  #    3=>[[3, "a"], [3, "c"], [3, "d"]],
  #    4=>[[4, "b"], [4, "c"]],
  #    5=>[[5, "b"], [5, "c"]],
  #    6=>[[6, "b"]],
  #    7=>[[7, "d"]]} 
g.merge(g) { |_,a| a.map(&:last) }
  #=> {1=>["a"], 2=>["a", "d"], 3=>["a", "c", "d"], 4=>["b", "c"],
  #    5=>["b", "c"], 6=>["b"], 7=>["d"]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
module HashReverser
  def invert_map
    each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), result|
      value.each { |v| (result[v] ||= []) << key }
    end
  end
end

original = {"a" => [1, 2, 3], "b" => [4, 5, 6], "c" => [3, 4, 5]}

original.extend(HashReverser).invert_map # => {1=>["a"], 2=>["a"], 3=>["a", "c"], 4=>["b", "c"], 5=>["b", "c"], 6=>["b"]}
```

Comment: `Object#extend` blows out the ruby method cache and is not recommended for runtime code.

Comment: Very nice, JJ. Note you don't need `self.`. Perhaps worth noting that `...with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }`, `{ |v| result << key }` is an alternative.  btw, I've found that `...(result[v] ||= []) << key` is generally the faster of the two. `include HashReverser` might be clearer.

Comment: Please explain your code and why it's the recommended solution. We're trying to educate, not just solve the immediate problem with the code.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution:

```
# Given
h = {"a" => [1, 2, 3], "b" => [4, 5, 6], "c" => [3, 4, 5], "d" => [7, 2, 3]}

h.flat_map {|k, v| v.product [k]}.group_by(&:first).each_value {|v| v.map! &:last }
```

Or:

```
h.flat_map {|k, v| v.product [k]}.reduce({}) {|o, (k, v)| (o[k] ||= []) << v; o}
```

The idea here is that we use `Array#product` to create a list of inverted single key-value pairs:

```
product = h.flat_map {|k, v| v.product([k]) }
# => [[1, "a"], [2, "a"], [3, "a"], [4, "b"], [5, "b"], [6, "b"], [3, "c"], [4, "c"], [5, "c"], [7, "d"], [2, "d"], [3, "d"]]
```

Group them by the value of the first item in each pair:

```
groups = product.group_by(&:first)
# => {1=>[[1, "a"]], 2=>[[2, "a"], [2, "d"]], 3=>[[3, "a"], [3, "c"], [3, "d"]], 4=>[[4, "b"], [4, "c"]], 5=>[[5, "b"], [5, "c"]], 6=>[[6, "b"]], 7=>[[7, "d"]]}
```

And then convert the values to a list of the last values in each pair:

```
result = groups.each_value {|v| v.map! &:last }
# => {1=>["a"], 2=>["a", "d"], 3=>["a", "c", "d"], 4=>["b", "c"], 5=>["b", "c"], 6=>["b"], 7=>["d"]}
```